Reference of Fermi energy in Quantum Espresso
I want to know what is the reference of Fermi energy calculated in scf run of Quantum Espresso.

What do you mean by reference Fermi energy? Do you mean the Fermi energy in the DOS/bands shifted to 0 eV in someone else's results and you to find the shift? It is not possible to know unless the person who publishes the result tells you! Or, if you mean you want to know the Fermi energy from your own calculation, check the end of the scf output file (or use grep Fermi scf.out). If your system is not metallic (or you are not using any smearing but using occupations='fixed'), then the top of the valence band can be taken as the Fermi level. For that, grep "highest occupied level" scf.out

I mean that every Eigenenergy is relative to some reference value. I know that Absolute values of Kohn sham eigenvalues are meaningless because there reference is ill defined quantity. Is this same for Fermi energy? or its reference is Work Function or any other quantity?

@RafiUllah The short answer is yes - the Fermi energy is meaningful relative to the Kohn Sham eigenvalues. Its absolute value is therefore just as meaningless as theirs.
